# Original Paper for "Bipartite Ramsey Theory" by Hattingh, Johannes H, 1998

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I'm trying to find the original paper "Bipartite Ramsey Theory" by Hattingh, Johannes H., Util. Math. 53 (1998), 217–230. However, I couldn't find it online except [Mathsci](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?batch_title=Selected%20Matches%20for%3A%20Items%20authored%20by%20Hattingh%2C%20Johannes%20H.&fmt=doc&pg1=INDI&s1=82450&searchin=&sort=citations&vfpref=html&r=2&mx-pid=1622032).

Does anyone happen to have the scan/link to the paper?

Comment: Asking the author might help: http://people.uncw.edu/hattinghj/

Comment: I have a copy (which I obtained via interlibrary loan, so no link).  I'm not sure what the rules are regarding sharing this copy.

Comment: @LouisD If possible, could you send a scanned version to me at xc329@cam.ac.uk, or could you let me know which library has this copy? Many thanks!